# Add variable to div inline style

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, dynamic-style

I want to set the background image of a div from the variable "imageUrl". I get the imageUrl from a variable in the js. The img src part of the html code works. But getting the variable into the style has not. Am I just not escaping the code correctly? Or not calling out the variable correctly? Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div class="slds-p-top_xxx-small" style="background-image: url('\'+imageUrl+\'');">
<p>
    Your newer selected image is: <lightning-formatted-url value={imageUrl}></lightning-formatted-url>
    <img src={imageUrl}>Test</img>
</p>
    <h1>Your screenname is {screenName}</h1>
    <h1>Your navLogic is {navLogic}</h1>
    <h1>Your Component Text is {componentText}</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "expressions" in LWC. You need to make a separate getter for this:

```
get imageUrlStyle() {
  return `background-image: url("${this.imageUrl}")`;
}
```

...

```
<div class="slds-p-top_xxx-small" style={imageUrlStyle}>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using something like this before but I got turned off by the errors I got in VS Code. I recently read where I could ignore them and it works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @JonathanCrow You'll eliminate a good potion of those errors if you add `// jshint esverson: 9` to the top of your JS source files, and configure eslint to use es9 as well (I forget how off the top of my head, but a simple Google search should be illuminating).